# RegEx to match a string starts with table tag exclude only alert word

Tags: javascript, java, regex

Need a regular expression to match a string contains table tag `<TABLE` and ends with `>`  in between it may have any character other than `alert` word.

For example: With regular expression for following String(html code) 2nd line shouldn't match if it have `alert` word otherwise it should match 2nd line

```html
 1. <DIV type="HEADER">
 2.      <TABLE border="0" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" width="655" onmouseover="alert('Table XSS')">
 3.          <COL width="313" />
 4.          <TBODY>
 5.             <TR valign="TOP">
 6.               <TD width="313">
 7.                       <P align="LEFT" style="margin-top: 0in">
 8.                         <IMG border="0" height="33" name="graphics3" src="/abc" width="74" />
 9.                       </P>
 10.                   </TD>
 11.               </TR>
 12.           </TBODY>
 13.       </TABLE> 
 14. </DIV>
```

I tried with this `<table(?!alert)[\s\S]*[^>]*>` regular expression but it's selecting 2nd line in above mentioned code.

Please help me to get appropriate regular expression to my requirement and thanks in advance.

Comment: You lost me by mentioning "HTML" and "regex" in the same sentence.  Please use a proper HTML parser here, not regex.

Comment: Java OR Javascript?

Comment: @Toto I need in Java but generic regex also fine, I can change to work with Java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Tim Biegeleisen rightly commented, this is a job that should be handled by an HTML parser or using the DOM methods. But if you must use a regex, consider the following:

```
/<TABLE(?![^>]*alert)[^>]*>/g
```

[See RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/35Mxtx/3/)

1. `<TABLE` matches `<Table` (obviously).
2. `(?![^>]*alert)` Uses a negative lookahead assertion to assert that `alert` does not appear before the next `>`.
3. `[^>]*` Matches 0 or more non-`>` characters.
4. `>` matches the closing `>` of the `<TABLE>` tag.

Comment: some how it helped for me. by altering (?![^>]*alert) with (?![^~]*alert) because > will use in html code.